# How does a CloudFront cache behavior's "Path Pattern" interact with the origin's "Origin Path"?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have an origin that looks like this: "https://myS3Bucket.s3/static/ui/v1.0.0". This origin has an "Origin Path" that is "/v1.0.0", and the cache behavior associated with this origin has a "Path Pattern" that is "/static/ui/*".

If a user makes a request to the CloudFront with the path "https://abcd1234.cloudfront.net/static/ui/index.html", what does the request that CloudFront makes to my origin look like? Does it become https://myS3Bucket.s3/static/ui/v1.0.0/index.html? Or does it become https://myS3Bucket.s3/v1.0.0/index.html?